# Should jquery scripts or remote: true option be used to implement ajax features in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

It seems that to add ajax features to a rails app, we can either directly add jquery scripts in views, like

```
$(#some_form).on('input', () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'some_url',
    method: 'verb',
    data: {some_data}
  }).trigger('input')
```

or we can use the rails way, which simply add `remote: true` to the form.
However, it seems that the jquery way is more flexible and allows better separation of front end and back end. Which one of the two ways should be recommended or is more practical in production?

Comment: Read Stackoverflow guidelines, this is mainly personal tastes and opinion, this question does not belong to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Rails way in fact is many times simpler as you can see that a form is remote by simply looking at the view. In your case, you have to go and find the associated handler and see what handler is doing. You also have to write good amount of boilerplate code at the risk of introducing bugs.

Following is the way Rails documentation provides

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements

You can even avoid writing any client side JS code by using js.erb view files to do what you want to happen on successful operation.

Ultimately, there is no perfect answer to this. There is always some trade-off.